# SOAP Request : Illegal Protocol https for HTTP URLConnection Factory

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, ioexception

**Problem :**

I'm calling a SOAP Webservice, but need to change the URL with each call. However, the end point within the wsdl was an internal address, so I am trying to edit the endpoint myself. Assuming this is the correct thing to do (?), I get  **java.io.IOException: Illegal Protocol https for HTTP URLConnection Factory** which I am struggling to resolve.

**Code :**

```
    OtherCompanyWebService ws = new OtherCompanyWebService();
    OtherCompanyWebServicePortType port = ws.getOtherCompanyWebServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint();
    ServiceRequest serviceRequest = makeMyServiceRequest();

    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
                  BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                  "https://blah.blah.com/blah/services/blahWebService.blahWebServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint");

    Staff staff = port.getStaffData(serviceRequest).getStaff().getValue();
```

**Stacktrace :**

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:199)
        at $Proxy52.getStudentData(Unknown Source)
        at uk.co.txttools.rm.service.RmServiceImpl.runRmJob(RmServiceImpl.java:209)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy12.runRmJob(Unknown Source)
        at uk.co.txttools.rm.quartz.RmJob.execute(RmJob.java:41)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:48)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:242)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:178)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Illegal Protocol https for HTTP URLConnection Factory.
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HttpURLConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(HttpURLConnectionFactoryImpl.java:44)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:480)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have found is far from ideal, but appears to work. If you have a better solution, please post it here.

The problem was that in the wsdl file, the endpoint was http. The error occurs because I'm changing the endpoint to be https. (Possibly this is a bug?)

To get round this, I am using a local version of the wsdl file, and putting in two endpoints, one http and one https. Then when I change the endpoint, I either change the http one or the https one, depending on whether I want http or https.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this message, I found out that I did not set an SSL context to my TLS client (WS).

If the code can be of any help :

```
/**
 * Configure mutal TLS on WS given in parameter
 * 
 * @param portType webservice
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void setTLS(Object ws) throws Exception {

    if (tlsClientParameters == null) {
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(ConfigUtils.getInstance().getProxyHost()) && StringUtils.hasLength(ConfigUtils.getInstance().getProxyPort())) {
            System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", ConfigUtils.getInstance().getProxyHost());
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", ConfigUtils.getInstance().getProxyPort());
        }

        X509Certificate[] certificatesChain = new X509Certificate[1];

        KeyManager[] managers = new KeyManager[1];

        Pkcs12 pkcs12 = new Pkcs12();
        pkcs12.login(new ClassPathResource(ConfigUtils.getInstance().getCertificateFileName()).getURI().getPath(), ConfigUtils.getInstance().getCertificatePassword());
        certificatesChain[0] = pkcs12.getCertificate();
        managers[0] = new SSLKeyManagers(certificatesChain, pkcs12.getKey());

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(portType);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        TrustManager[] trustManager = getServerTrustManager();

        sslContext.init(managers, trustManager, null);
        HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

        tlsClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
        if (trustManager != null) {
            tlsClientParameters.setTrustManagers(trustManager);
        }
        tlsClientParameters.setKeyManagers(managers);
        tlsClientParameters.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        tlsClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(false);

        conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);

    } else {

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(portType);
        HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

        conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);
    }
}

/**
 * 
     * Gets the trust manager
 *  
 * @return keystore
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws KeyStoreException
 * @throws ResourceException 
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws CertificateException 
 */
private static TrustManager[] getServerTrustManager() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, ResourceException {

    TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

    trustStore.load(new ClassPathResource(ConfigUtils.getInstance().getServerKeyStoreFileName()).getInputStream(), ConfigUtils.getInstance().getServerKeystorePassword().toCharArray());

    factory.init(trustStore);       
    return factory.getTrustManagers();
}
```